# Nokogiri : Not able to access "p" tag text with "a" tag link

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

My HTML code is this :

```
<h3>Head1</h3>
<p>text before link<a href="http://www.google.com" title="http://www.google.com"    target="_blank">Link 1</a>text after link</p>
<h3>Head2</h3>
<p>text before link<a href="http://www.google.com" title="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link 2</a>text after link</p>
<h3>Head3</h3>
<p>text before link<a href="http://www.google.com" title="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link 3</a>text after link</p>
```

I am using NOKOGIRI for the HTML parsing.
In Above case,
Suppose above html code is in @text

```
@page_data = Nokogiri::HTML(@text)
@headings = @page_data.css('h3')
@desc = @page_data.css('p')
```

But in @desc , It only return the text ,It will not create the link for "Link 1","Link 2","Link 3".

Becoz the link is present in between the text , So i can not link it separately again.
How can i achieve the text with link in "p" tag in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear about what you are trying to accomplish. If by this...

> How can i achieve the text with link in "p" tag in this case?

...you mean, *"How can I get the HTML contents of each `<p>` tag?"* then this will do it:

```
require "nokogiri"
frag = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(my_html)
frag.css('h3').each do |header|
  puts header.text
  para = header.next_element
  puts para.inner_html
end
#=> Head1
#=> text before link<a href="http://www.google.com" title="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link 1</a>text after link
#=> Head2
#=> text before link<a href="http://www.google.com" title="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link 2</a>text after link
#=> Head3
#=> text before link<a href="http://www.google.com" title="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link 3</a>text after link
```

If instead you mean *"How do I get just the text of the anchor in each paragraph?"* then you could either do this:

```
frag.css('h3').each do |header|
  anchor = header.next_element.at_css('a')
  puts "#{header.text}: #{anchor.text}"
end
#=> Head1: Link 1
#=> Head2: Link 2
#=> Head3: Link 3
```

...or you could do this:

```
frag.xpath('.//p/a').each do |anchor|
  puts anchor.text
end
#=> Link 1
#=> Link 2
#=> Link 3
```

If none of these are what you want, then please edit your question to more clearly explain what you want as the end result.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question. My problem was i m not able to access the HTML contents of each <p> tag. Thanks Phrogz. Your solution solved my problem. :)

Comment: @Prasad Glad to have helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that when an answer solves your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153741).

Comment: Hey Guys , This link will help you to work with Nokogiri : http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/